# How to include functions from a shell script from a different folder

Tags: shell, directory-structure

I have a directory structure of type

```
|--bringup-scripts
|  |--prep.sh
|--scripts
|  |--i2c0.func
|  |--bit.func
```

The ***prep.sh*** looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

. ../scripts/i2c0.func
```

The ***i2c0.func*** looks like this :

```
#!/bin/sh

. ./bit.func
```

As there is a dependency of ***i2c0.func*** on ***bit.func*** ,If I run ***prep.sh*** from the ***bringup-scripts*** folder,it throws an error saying

> ./bit.func: No such file or directory

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is not using relativ paths, instead defining a starting point for all scripts in the **prep.sh** file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ROOT_DIR="$(dirname $PWD)"

. $ROOT_DIR/scripts/i2c0.func
```

You have to include `$ROOT_DIR` as a prefix for every script in the **scripts** directory too, e.g.:

**i2c0.func**

```
#!/bin/sh

. $ROOT_DIR/scripts/bit.func
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a standard way to do this, but you could try changing **i2c0.func** like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

. ../scripts/bit.func
```

Though note **prep.sh** gets its caller's working directory, so it will only work when you run it from `bringup-scripts/` or `scripts/`.

Comment: Thanks,but there are files in the scripts folder too,that use i2c0.func file,This would'nt be very efficient for them

Comment: @YashGupta How not?

Comment: I am not sure about the performance efficiency,but would like to have something more genric as I have many similar dependencies